# Irrationality of e and farey fractions

Tags: irrational-numbers

How do we go about proving that 
$$[k! e] = k! \sum_{j=0 -> k} \frac{1}{j!}$$
I know that we could write 
$$e = \sum_{j=0 -> \infty} \frac{1}{j!}$$ 
But I don't see how that's going to help in the proof...

Comment: $$k!e = k!\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!} + \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty \frac{k!}{j!}.$$ See that the second sum is smaller than $1$ and the first sum an integer.

Comment: Ohhhh!! I should sleep... I can't believe I didn't see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch proof:
$$k!e=k!+\frac{k!}{2}+\cdots+1+k!\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}$$
If with $[\ ]$ you mean the integer for proof is:
$$k!\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}<1$$
So:
$$[k!e]=k!+\frac{k!}{2}+\cdots+1$$
$$[k!e]=k!\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!}$$